# Why can't I import my Mass Effect 2 save?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm trying to import my savegame of Mass Effect 2 to Mass Effect 3. I put it in the correct folder and the game finds it normally, but I can't select it. I pick Michael Shepard (my character) and it shows the game date it was played, but I can't select it. I keep pressing the select button but nothing works.

Comment: Just a quick check: Did you complete Mass Effect 2? Otherwise you can't import the save file.

Comment: did you perhaps fail the game as in everyone died in mass effect 2 at the end

Comment: Are you playing on PC?  Is there any error message?

Comment: There is no error message, i just pick my character, and then i keep pressing the import button, but nothing changes. I click on it nonstop but nothing changes. I completed the game with 0 casualties aka all survived, finished Mass effect 2 fully, with all DLC's.

Comment: You won't do anything by just clicking. Reinstall the game and make sure you REALLY have completed ME2 saves. If won't help - than use help.ea.com.

Comment: Did you install the game through steam?

Answer (score 2):

Reinstall the game and if that doesen't work, try going back to a previous save in ME2 and then continue to the end of the game, then import that file.